# Where does the "mixing" occur in convex combination of Girsanov measures?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

In [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362749/what-is-the-drift-for-a-convex-combination-of-girsanov-measures), Ofer says that taking the convex combination of two Girsanov measures yields a drift $BF_1+(1-B)F_2$ where $B$ is a Bernoulli random variable with parameter $\lambda$, independent of the underlying probability measure. I am a bit confused - where does the mixing occur? Why do we have to enlarge the space?

Since $\mu=\lambda\mu_1+(1-\lambda)\mu_2$ is a Girsanov measure there is a drift in the original space, you shouldn't have to enlarge it, right?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean precisely by mixing?

Comment: @NateRiver I just mean that we are "mixing" over $F_1$ and $F_2$